# Routing configuration in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3

I am trying to implement routing in cakephp. I want the urls to mapped like this...

www.example.com/nodes/main -> www.example.com/main
www.example.com/nodes/about -> www.example.com/about

So for this I wrote in my config/routes.php file..

```
Router::connect('/:action', array('controller' => 'nodes'));
```

Now, I got the thing going but when I click on the links, the url in browser appears like
www.example.com/nodes/main
www.example.com/nodes/about

Is there some way where I can get the urls to appear the way they are routed?
Setting in .htaccess or httpd.conf would be easy - but I don't have access to that.

Regards
Vikram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Router::connect('/main', array('controller' => 'nodes', 'action' => 'main'));
Router::connect('/about', array('controller' => 'nodes', 'action' => 'about'));
```

You may also do something more powerful, like this:

```
$actions = array('main','about');
foreach ($actions as $action){
   Router::connect('/$action', array('controller' => 'nodes', 'action' => '$action'));
}
```

Comment: Hi there
This is already working for me using the code I wrote. Its just the issue of URL appearing in address bar that I am looking to address.

Comment: uhm, i've seen that happeining. I don't remember why, right now but i'll take a look. Have you try with the writing the controllers? Becouse in your code those are missing, then, are interpreted like the actual controller working.

Comment: All right! That was the problem. I wasn't writing the controller when using the link helper, and since I had default controller set "nodes", that is why it was displaying the controller as well as action in the address bar. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

Basically if your links are created with Html helper, with the following format:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('your link', array('controller'=>'nodes', 'action'=>'main'));?>
```

Then the Cake will convert the links properly to www.example.com/main

But if your links are

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('your link', '/nodes/main/');?>
```

they will point to www.example.com/nodes/main